# Is it possible to use structured binding in the member initializer list of a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17

I would like to create a class with several `const` member variables. Unfortunately, the function I need to initialize those variables is from a very C-style external library. As a result, I have been employing the following "middle-man" of sorts:

```cpp
struct Struct {
    int foo, bar;
    Struct(int baz, int qux) {
        initializerFunction(&foo, baz, &bar, qux);
    }
}
class Class {
    const int foo, bar;
    Class(Struct s) : anArray(s.foo), anotherArray(s.bar) {}
public:
    Class(int baz, int quz) : Class(Struct(baz, qux)) {}
}
```

However, I somewhat dislike this construction. I was hoping to be able to do something like this instead:

```cpp
class Class {
    const int foo, bar;
public:
    Class(int baz, int qux) : [foo, bar](Struct(baz, qux)) {}
}
```

Is it possible that I am just using incorrect syntax, or is structured binding truly not allowed in the member initializer list of a constructor?

Comment: Obligatory: private `const` data members bring essentially no value to the table and cause a ton of trouble. I would just make make the members non-`const` and move on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structured bindings declare variables (well, they're not "variables" per-se, but nevermind). You cannot use structured bindings to manipulate existing objects. This includes member objects.