# Structured binding in constructor initialization list?

Tags: c++, structured-bindings, ctor-initializer

This is similar in vein to [Is it possible to use structured binding in the member initializer list of a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729216/is-it-possible-to-use-structured-binding-in-the-member-initializer-list-of-a-con), except that in my case, it is not a dislike-versus-like scenario rather it is a how-to-solve-it question.

I have two classes that I cannot touch and a free-standing function that constructs one object of each type and returns them as a pair:

```
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    A() = delete;
    explicit A(int) {}
};

struct B
{
    B() = delete;
    explicit B(char) {}
};

std::pair<A, B> func() // Same issue when pair is replaced with tuple
{
    return { A{42}, B{'F'} };
}
```

I can touch neither `A` nor `B`.  `func()` does a good amount of common work to construct objects of `A` and `B`.

Now to the problem at hand, showing my different attempts:

Attempt 1: Try structured binding in ctor initializer-list

```
class Foo
{
    A a;
    B b;
    public:
    Foo() : [a, b] { func() }
    // error: expected identifier before '[' token
    // Not resolved when '{func()}' is replaced with '= func()' or '(func))'
    {
    }
};
```

Attempt 2: Use `std::tie` in lieu of structured binding

```
class Foo
{
    A a;
    B b;
    public:
    Foo() : std::tie(a, b) = func() }
    // error: expected class-name before '(' token at column 21
    {
    }
};
```

Attempt 3: Construction within body, but (of course) it won't work

```
// error: use of deleted functions 'A::A()' and 'B:B()'
class Foo
{
    A a;
    B b;
    public:
    Foo()
    {
        const auto& p{func()};
        a = p.first;
        b = p.second;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional approach is to use a delegating constructor.

```cpp
class Foo
{
    A a;
    B b;
    Foo(std::pair<A, B> p) : a(p.first), b(p.second) {}

public:
    Foo() : Foo(func()) {}    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
class Foo
{
    std::pair<A, B> ab;
    public:
    Foo() : ab { func() }
    {
    }
};
```

or

```
class Foo
{
    A a;
    B b;
    public:
    Foo() : a { func().first }, b { func().second }
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Your second snippet is simply wrong. It invokes `func()` twice. In general case, `func`may be not `constexpr` or deterministic. First snippet is very performant, because of invoking direct initialization on subobjects, but needs accessor functions for pair members.

Comment: It's not simply wrong with the shown code in the question.

Comment: Come on! That's just an illustration and I am sure you're much smarter than that. Why make a twist to later untie? A common use case could be an allocation function that must not run twice. It's wrong, because it doesn't consider the most generic case, nor the most likely case.

Comment: "Simply" word used wrongly. It's not always wrong meant by "simply", it's "sometimes" wrong.

Comment: What about "often" wrong? One could argue semantics all day long, but my take is that calling the function multiple times like that is a bad smell unless you expect different values on subsequent calls. To call it twice and only use one of the return values each time is absolutely somthing I'd call out in review.

Comment: @sweenish stay away from me. The 2nd option is based on the Q code and it's just an option not mandatary to use.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are also just options and not mandatory to use.  But we still call it out when it's put in an answer. They are also typically based on the question's code.

Comment: I agreed that I might have used excessively strong words. But in case the second snippet were an option(`constexpr` or at least deterministic `func`), there would be no questions to answer. In the most generic likely case, `func` has to be called only once per ctor call. I believe the generic case is also the most likely case(e.g. resource allocator that returns error code alongside the resource descriptor).